# How to line up shapes horizontaly in css and displaying text on right left corner

Tags: html, css

I have 3 boxes that i am trying to line up..

```
 .box {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background: #8C8C8C;
      margin:0 auto;
      border: solid 4px grey;
    text-align: center;
    display:block;


      }
```

Display inlineblock is not working also it kills centering

HTML

```
<div class="box"(click)="boxnumber('1')" >


      <p class="count1">{{item1count}}<p>
  </div>

  <br>
  <div class="box" (click)="boxnumber('2')" >
    <p class="count2">{{item2count}}<p>

  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="box" (click)="boxnumber('3')" >
    <p class="count3">{{item3count}}<p>

  </div>
```

Also i am trying to display item1count,item2count,item3count numbers on right down corner of each box.count1 count2 css classes are empty now because i am not sure what to write in them.

[boxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Xoys.png)

Comment: "right down corner" - do you mean *bottom-right corner* of the element `.box`?

Comment: you can remove br tag and add margin to box like https://jsfiddle.net/tmc1joso/2/

Comment: yes bottom right corner

Comment: For bottom right corner you need to add vertical align, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `br` tag and replace `display:block` to `inline-block`

```css
.box {
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 background: #8C8C8C;
 margin:0 auto;
 border: solid 4px grey;
 text-align: center;
 display:inline-block;
}
.boxes {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
<div class="box"(click)="boxnumber('1')" >
      <p class="count1">{{item1count}}<p>
  </div>
  <div class="box" (click)="boxnumber('2')" >
    <p class="count2">{{item2count}}<p>

  </div>
  <div class="box" (click)="boxnumber('3')" >
    <p class="count3">{{item3count}}<p>

  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: "inline-block" will only display them inline i.e. next to each other.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding css `margin: 0px auto;` to your `.box` to center them.

try this:

```
.box{
  width:50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid red;

  margin: 15px auto;
  display: table;
}
```

To display the number in the right corner you need to add vertical alignment, like so:

```
.box p{
  vertical-align:bottom;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

You can take a look at my [plunkr here](https://plnkr.co/edit/7emzUPTEpMFho3tpYneX?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <style>
    .box {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background: #8C8C8C;
       float: left;
       margin-right:10px;
      border: solid 4px grey;
    text-align: center;
      }
      .box-container{
        width:204px; /* 50*3+(4*2)*3+10*3 */
        margin:0 auto;
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="box-container">
<div class="box"(click)="boxnumber('1')" >


      <p class="count1">{{item1count}}<p>
  </div>


  <div class="box" (click)="boxnumber('2')" >
    <p class="count2">{{item2count}}<p>

  </div>

  <div class="box" (click)="boxnumber('3')" >
    <p class="count3">{{item3count}}<p>

  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```